# Why does Hashem' anger flare when Balaam goes with the Moabite officials?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-balak, bilam

"God came to Balaam at night and said to him, "If these men have come to call for you, arise and go with them, but the word I speak to you-that you shall do.
In the morning Balaam arose, saddled his she-donkey and went with the Moabite dignitaries.
God's wrath flared because he was going, and an angel of the Lord stationed himself on the road to thwart him."

Why did he get so angry, when he agreed for him to go with them?
i came across this while reading the Torah portion this Shabbat and thought it was odd, so i thought i'd ask on here.

(unsure if they were princes, or officials or what, the thing i read it from said princes... i think)

Comment: “In the way that a person wishes to go, we lead him” (Makkos 10b). Hashem allowed him to go, but that doesn’t mean He was happy (as it were) about it. I’d post this as an answer, but I see that Rashi only applies this much later in the story, and not at this point.

Comment: I believe the midrash says that Hashem was upset because even though Bilaam agreed to only say what Hashem would let him say, Bilaam left with intentions to "persuade" Hashem to "change his mind". If I new an exact source I would have posted this as an answer.

Comment: @Rafael Rashi says that to answer a different question on the preceding passuk.

Comment: I believe his sin was in asking again after Gd said no to his first request.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73830/170